# How do I fix compilation errors when integrating OpenFeint with cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

[image: screenshot of compilation errors]

When I attempt to use OpenFeint with cocos2d, I get compilation errors like those shown in the screenshot. How can I fix these errors?

Comment: Specifically, "As you see new answers to your question, vote up the helpful ones by clicking the upward pointing arrow to the left of the answer." Also, "When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer." This is straight from the stackoverflow FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add Framework `MobileCoreServices.framework` to your Xcode project.

To elaborate, these are the frameworks that you have to add to your project in addition to other frameworks that Cocos2D or your app uses:

- Foundation
- UIKit
- CoreGraphics
- QuartzCore
- Security
- SystemConfiguration
- libsqlite3.0.dylib
- MobileCoreServices (used to be called CoreServices)
- CFNetwork
- AddressBook
- AddressBookUI
- GameKit
- CoreLocation
- MapKit
- libz.1.2.3.dylib

Reference: http://support.openfeint.com/dev/readme-for-openfeint-ios-sdk-2-9-1/

Comment: then you ought to add more details. i know for sure this openfeint sdk works because my game successfully integrates to it and so did many other games. there might something wrong with your code or implementation that you need to post here. we can't read minds.